Counterspelling a Counterspell - not allowed anymore?
In PHB 2024 there's a much needed, simplier rule for multiple spell casting, it just says: "Only one spell that costs a spell slot per turn" (my wording).
To counterspell a spell (from character A) it's important to know that technically it's the turn of character A and therefore the Counterspell (from character B) is independent on the actions of other characters, because it's not their turn. That has not changed in 2024, as far as I know.
But what if character A wants to counterspell the Counterspell from character B? Is it technical A's turn and, therefore, A can't countercounterspell (if A used a spell slot with the first spell), or is there a special loophole in the regular round-turn-system for this situation? (just out of curiosity: What would be the answer in regard of the 2014 edition: In whose turn happens the counter-counterspell?)

You can look up Counterspell, it's right here in the Free Rules on D&D Beyond
https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/2619072-counterspell

@TreeSpawned Thanks for pointing out. I will adapt my question.

After reading the exact spell description (thanks to @TreeSpawned), I think I am wrong!
Because, a successful Counterspell means that character A didn't spent a spell slot at all, so A could cast a spell again - but: he wasted his action (casting), so he cannot cast Counterspell with his action, but he could do so with his reaction (couldn't he?). But after this, A and B can't interfere anymore, because there is only one reaction per round. It would need character C to countercountercounterspell the first spell of A, and A can't do anything about it (unless A has magical equipment which can counterspell as well).

You can never cast counterspell with an action, it is always a reaction

Correct, and I wrote that 'A could cast a spell again'. But, you're right; I left out "even if it would be possible" in the next part of that sentence. I wanted to be brief, but that could be misleading, thanks for noticing!
